# Regex: how to match an word that doesn't end with a specific character

Tags: php, regex, numbers, cpu-word, match

I would like to match the whole "word"—one that starts with a number character and that may include special characters but does not end with a '%'.

Match these:

- 112 (whole numbers)
- 10-12 (ranges)
- 11/2 (fractions)
- 11.2 (decimal numbers)
- 1,200 (thousand separator)

but not

- 12% (percentages)
- A38 (words starting with a alphabetic character)

I've tried these regular expressions:

```
(\b\p{N}\S)*)
```

but that returns '12%' in '12%'

```
(\b\p{N}(?:(?!%)\S)*)
```

but that returns '12' in '12%'

Can I make an exception to the `\S` term that disregards `%`?
Or will have to do something else?

I'll be using it in PHP, but just write as you would like and I'll convert it to PHP.

Comment: Do these numbers appear in some context? Spaces surrounding etc.? Specifically why did you use the trailing `\S` (which means non-space)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This matches your specification:

```
\b\p{N}\S*+(?<!%)
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b       # Start of number
\p{N}    # One Digit
\S*+     # Any number of non-space characters, match possessively
(?<!%)   # Last character must not be a %
```

The [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) `\S*+` makes sure that the regex engine will not backtrack into a string of non-space characters it has already matched. Therefore, it will not "give back" a `%` to match `12` within `12%`.

Of course, that will also match `1!abc`, so you might want to be more specific than `\S` which matches anything that's not a whitespace character.

Comment: +1, but if you make the `\S*` possessive - `\S*+` - you can get rid of the `(?=\s|$)`.

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. I've extended it a bit to fit some other cases that i discovered.

`(\b\p{N}\S*+(?<!%|%\p{P}|%\p{P}\p{P}))`
So it disregards '12%.', '11%-12%', '( 12%)', and '( 12%).' 

In my data % is followed by a max of two punctations, but i sure the code above can be converted to something more general if needed.

Answer (score 1):

> Can i make an exception to the \S term that disregards %

Yes you can:

```
[^%\s]
```

See this expression `\b\d[^%\s]*` [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v81d)

Comment: But he said that only the *last* character must not be a `%`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker thats true, then I showed only the way to exclude a specific character from a predefined class, because the correct answer is already there from you (+1)

Comment: Yeah, he asked for that (exclusion of a single character), too. So we don't really know what he actually needs :) +1!

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely be using this a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

KISS (restrictive):

```
/[0-9][0-9.,-/]*\s/
```

Comment: That will match `12` in `12%`.

Comment: I assume the OP is looking for "numbers" so "7ISNOTANUMBER" shouldn't match, ergo there should be some kind of separator (that I assumed to be whitespace).

Answer (score 1):

```
\d+([-/\.,]\d+)?(?!%)
```

Explanation:

```
\d+        one or more digits
(
   [-/\.,]     one "-", "/", "." or ","
   \d+         one or more digits
)?         the group above zero or one times
(?!%)      not followed by a "%" (negative lookahead)
```

Comment: +1.  Judging by the examples provided, I suspect this is the answer to the question the OP *should have* asked. ;)

Comment: @AlanMoore: Careful, this will match `1` in `12%`. The quantifiers  should also be made possessive. Then it will work.

Comment: @Tim: Can I recover from this gaffe by saying I assumed there would be word boundaries or anchors around the regex?  :P

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
preg_match("/^[0-9].*[^%]$/", $string);
```

Comment: That fails to match single-digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this PCRE regex:

```
/^(\d[^%]+)$/
```

It should give you what you need.

Comment: Only the last character cannot be a percent.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just:

```
(\b[\p{N},.-]++(?!%))
```

That's not very exact regarding decimal delimiters or ranges. (As example). But the `++` possessive quantifier will eat up as many decimals as it can. So that you really just need to check the following character with a simple assertion. Did work for your examples.

Comment: OP did say the first character had to be a number, and you're not enforcing that.  The leading `\b` doesn't do the trick; it will match (e.g.) the comma in `foo,bar`.

Comment: Like I said, not very exact. Correct range and fractions treatment has been answered by etuardu.